# How to get cycles bake progress in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, texture-baking

I can bake to textures using `bpy.ops.object.bake()`. But because this function waits until completion, I then use this: `bpy.ops.object.bake("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`.

Then it displays this:

[image: Bake progress]

I also found this in Blender's source (object_bake_api.c):

```cpp
typedef struct BakeAPIRender {
    /* DOESNT MATTER TO THIS QUESTION */

    int result;
    bool ready;

    /* callbacks */
    Render *render;
    float *progress;
    short *do_update;

    /* for redrawing */
    ScrArea *sa;
} BakeAPIRender;

/* callbacks */

static void bake_progress_update(void *bjv, float progress)
{
    BakeAPIRender *bj = bjv;

    if (bj->progress && *bj->progress != progress) {
        *bj->progress = progress;

        /* make jobs timer to send notifier */
        *(bj->do_update) = true;
    }
}
```

I'd want to get that `progress` variable, but this code is C++. So how can I get bake progress using Python scripts? Any suggestions?

PS: I also couldn't find any information in the documentation.

PS2: Or maybe some kind of time approximation, so the user would at least know how much time it's going to take.

Comment: It's probably not exposed to Python at all. Might not be trivial.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Well, I hope they put support for that in a future version. I actually don't need this anymore.

Comment: Wonder if this is still the case 6 years later