# cycles bake progress in python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, baking

This is asked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32798/how-to-get-cycles-bake-progress-in-python) as well, but since that is a year old... is this possible by now to get the bake progress trough python ?

Comment: Hi. A question being old is not a reason to re-ask it.

Comment: i wanted to comment on it but i couldn't...